# Name driver is not defined for selenium

Tags: python, firefox

this is the error which  i  have got when executed the code

[image]

and the code is

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the variable driver before using it.
It should look something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(path_to_driver_dir)
driver.get("http://google.com")
```